# How to disable cache when loading images

Tags: android, caching, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am using Glide image library with a Recycler View to load hundreds of images as the user scrolls down from website URL's.The problem is that glide is caching all these images thus increasing app size to a lot of un-needed disk space. Thus I want to disable cache.Unfortunately I am not getting an exact method to do so yet.

I tried using

`Glide.with(context)
                    .load(itemList.get(position)
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .getPhoto()).into(holder.Photo);`

where itemList.get(position) contains URL
but this is not being accepted with a not defined error in android studio.

What would be a good solution to this problem. Any other libraries which can help for loading images from URL is also appriciated.

Edit: .diskCacheStratergy, .skipMemoryCache and .signature dosn't seem to work inside Adapters where I am loading all the images

Edit 2:There was a problem in the build I think .diskCacheStratergy and .skipMemoryCache options came once I refreshed and synced my app.gradle again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using     .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.NONE )

```
   Glide  
        .with( context )
        .load( eatFoodyImages[0] )
        .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.NONE )
        .skipMemoryCache( true )
        .into( imageViewInternet );
```

for more please check this link https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics

Answer (score 0):

You can try your code similar to the code below:

```
Glide.with(DemoActivity.this)
     .load(Uri.parse("file://" + imagePath))
     .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
     .into(mImage);
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Glide  
    .with(context)
    .load(itemList.get(position).getPhoto())
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
    .skipMemoryCache(true)
    .into(holder.Photo);
```